# macOS Monterey12.0+Python+Selenium+Chrome: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH & “chromedriver” can’t be opened

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver, mac

I am facing following multiple issues with Python + Selenium + Chrome :

> **WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in
> PATH.**

> **“chromedriver” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for
> malicious software.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

- Download chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip [Check and find appropriate version [**here**](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)]
- Open termial and execute below cmd

```
   sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin 
   sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver 
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

- If you still observe "chromedriver can't be opened", then execute

```
  which chromedriver
```

- Expected to return simillar to : `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`
- Just to trust on chromedriver execute

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```